# How to find what query executes while doing reindexing?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, catalogsearch, reindex, advanced-search

I have a custom module that added some re-indexing rows in `System->Index Management`.

Currently its giving some issue. While doing it manually site goes down.

Is there any way to find out **what query executes while doing this custom re indexing**?

I think there must be any core file where we can print all the queries while doing any re-indexing manually. I am searching for this.

Answer (score 1):

In `app\etc\local.xml` where are database settings add `<profiler>true</profiler>` tag so it should look like that

`<default_setup>
    <connection>
        <profiler>true</profiler>
        <host><![CDATA[****]]></host>
        <username><![CDATA[***]]></username>
        <password><![CDATA[***]]></password>
        <dbname><![CDATA[***]]></dbname>
        <active>1</active>
    </connection>
</default_setup>`

and then in `Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php` make to changes :

- `$_debug` set to `true`
- `$_logAllQueries` set to `true`
- `$_logCallStack` set to `true`

And try to make some action (for example `reindex`) than in file `var\debug\sql.txt` you will find all executed sql queries + stack trace.